# Architecture/Technical Challenges in Handling Authentication/Permissions in Elixir Channels/Sockets

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

So I have decided to rewrite an application I have been writing in Node.js to Elixir because of all the extra complexity working with Node that Elixir comes with out of the box.

My issue was something I didn't have quite right in Node and is becoming just as complex in Elixir and I am not entirely sure how to go about approaching it.

I am trying to recreate a lot of how Discord does permissions.  I am essentially building a CRM system, with different roles like "Sales Manager", "Sales", "Customer Service Rep" etc...  But they all are able to do different things based on their "role".

Some things I need to do is be able to update a permission on the fly for a person or role.  Maybe the "Sales Manager" role can't look at company financial data like an "Accountant" but we need to give that specific person access for a few days.  Or I have a "Customer Service Rep" and we give that entire role the ability to add things to a calendar. I also would like to have the ability to kill sessions.

So there are a few ways I've seen said around Elixir forums, like:

- Using Guardian, I really want to like tokens and think not having to hit the database every time sounds wonderful, but I don't think it's practical for this.  Unless there is a good solution to updating tokens on the fly which I haven't found.
- Giving each person their own process and just kill and start the process on changes with new changes.  This seems pretty neat, but I'd rather not kill processes unless there is an actual error, I think this solution will come with big problems, like tracing problems.  Although I am not familiar enough to know if this might actually cause problems, or if this is a bad solution for other reasons.
- Use Guardian with Guardian_DB, which then defeats the purpose of using tokens, but at least I'd have a trackable session.  My only problem with this is I do plan on using a load-balancer so that if a socket connection dies I can reconnect it to the same server and I am not sure there is a way to do that with tokens or if the socket itself has a session attached to it.  This is not really that big of an issue though and is pretty close to what I had with Node.js.
- Use Redis which I'd like to stay away from, and then update session data in Redis based on user_id when updates occur and hit Redis on every request to see if the user has permissions.  I plan to put this across multiple servers eventually which means ETS is not viable unless I can load-balance socket connections like I could in Node.js.

So I guess my questions are,

- Can I attach sessions to sockets?  Is this a bad idea?
- Should I still use a token, and just use Redis to check the token on every request?
- Is a token still a better choice than a session?
- Is there a much better/easier solution that I have not even mentioned?

I'm sorry this was pretty drawn out and long, I've never had to do something as permission bound as this project professionally and am pretty new to Elixir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoenix channels are stateful. You can put data in the `assigns` field and it stays there for the duration of the connection. That is where you normally put your user_id after authenticating the user on join.

I also use the channels assigns to store client state that I need on the server.

WRT to the role to permissions question, I'm doing exactly this. What I do is load the load the role permissions from the database on startup and build an ETS store with them. You can do the same with a Task or a GenServer. If the permissions change for a given role, i update the database and the ETS table.

My user model supports a list of roles for each user.

When in need to validate the permissions for a given user, I call the Permission model api like `Permission.has_permission?("create-room", user, scope)`. I have two level of permissions, global and per room. That is what the scope is used for.

Comment: So I know ETS tables only work on that specific machine.  I probably don't need to distribute them, but if I do I know I can't do that with ETS tables.

Would something like Mnesia be the answer?